# Get the closest weekday according to the chosen day

Tags: php, date

I want to check if the chosen day (for an example 25 every month) are a weekend or not.

If it's not a weekend (Saturday or Sunday), then the chosen day will remain. But if the day is a weekend, the chosen day will be moved to the closest weekday (Monday to Friday).

**Examples**

```
2016-03-24 is a Thursday.
2016-03-25 is a Friday.
2016-03-26 is a Saturday.
2016-03-27 is a Sunday.
2016-03-28 is a Monday.
```

If the day is 26 for this month, the closest weekday is Friday. If the day is 27 for this month, the closest weekday is a Monday. And so on...

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: moved back or forward to closest weekday?

Comment: @mitkosoft As in the example. If the day is Sunday, the closest weekday is Monday, but if the day are on a Saturday, the closest weekday are on a Friday.

Comment: @j08691 I haven't tried anything since I don't know how to do this.

Comment: in light of j08691 's comment, I am getting rather appalled at the number of SO questions these days that amount to, "i have a simple programming task, please write it for me..."

Comment: @Todd If you was in my position, where I am very tired and have a massive headache and I can't wait with this function due to a deadline, you would understand why I'm asking you guys.

Comment: I completely understand why youre asking, hence my comment. My position is unchanged (though, I guess perhaps its even lessened, since now youre trying to justify it as well). So, again, as you were asked above, "what have you tried?" Are you the least bit familiar with the policies and rules about posting on SO? Its rather unscrupulous to just expect people to do your work for you, while asking for help with existing code that isnt working is acceptable. Reading the SO index page these days is just pages and pages of the same thing... (interesting that theyre almost always PHP too).

Comment: Thank you for understanding. If you read my other questions I have posted here on Stack Overflow, you'll see that I often give you guys a code of what I have tried with. Maybe 8 of 10 questions I've asked, contains a "I have tried the following" code. Yesterday was not a good day for me so I just break the rules a little this time (again?). I'm sorry for doing that and it will not happen again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this

```
function getClosestWeekday($dateString) {
    $date = new DateTime($dateString);
    $weekday = $date->format("N");
    if ($weekday == 6) {
        $date = $date->sub(new DateInterval("P1D"));
    } else if ($weekday == 7) {
        $date = $date->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
    }
    return $date;
}
var_dump(getClosestWeekday("2016-03-24")); // returns 2016-03-24
var_dump(getClosestWeekday("2016-03-25")); // returns 2016-03-25
var_dump(getClosestWeekday("2016-03-26")); // returns 2016-03-25
var_dump(getClosestWeekday("2016-03-27")); // returns 2016-03-28
var_dump(getClosestWeekday("2016-03-28")); // returns 2016-03-28
```

The fact that you don't know how to do this, doesn't justify that you didn't try anything. PHP.net gives you all the tools to at least get on the way to do it.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<?php
$day = date('l', strtotime('2009-10-24'));
if($day == 'Saturday'){
  echo 'Friday';
} else if($day == 'Sunday'){
  echo 'Monday';
} else {
  echo $day;
}
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

In the following example I'll show you the shortest and (in my opinion) best option to get the next weekday.

```
// Create a new DateTime object
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2016-03-25')->modify('-1 day');

// Modify the date to get the next weekday
$date->modify('next weekday');

// Output the date
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

The thing that makes `DateTime``so great is that it is very flexible and makes it possible for you to just 'try' things like the above.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. Your code was really short but if you take a look at Alessandro's code, it calculates where the closest weekday is, therefore the right answer. Your code just skips to the next day, even if the current day is a weekday. You can however prevent that with a if but you wanted it to be the shortest :)

Comment: @ErikEdgren I modified my answer. It now jumps back one day so that if today is a weekday, it will jump to today. Otherwise it will jump to monday :)

Comment: Nice :) But it still dosen't act like I want it to do :P Please see my example in my question.

Answer (score 0):

So, to simplify, if is Sat, should be moved -1 day, if is Sun, should be moved +1, otherwhise remains as is:

```
<?php
    function changeDate($date) {
        if (date("N", strtotime($date)) == 6) {
            return date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 day ", strtotime($date)));
        } elseif (date("N", strtotime($date)) == 7) {
            return date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day ", strtotime($date)));
        } else {
            return date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
        }
    }

    echo changeDate("2016-03-25"); //Friday
    echo '<br>';
    echo changeDate("2016-03-26"); //Saturday 
    echo '<br>';
    echo changeDate("2016-03-27"); //Sunday
?>
```

Output:

```
2016-03-25 //not changed
2016-03-25 //moved -1 day
2016-03-28 //moved +1 day
```